# When to use empty object over null object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am encountering a situation where I don't know should I use a null object or an empty object. I have a state which has a question object to hold the current question. At the first state of the screen, there is no current question, so I intend to assign the question object to an empty object instead of a null object. I use this strategy by following the code example in the Bloc page.

Here is the code example on the BlocLibrary page:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class User extends Equatable {
  const User(this.id);

  final String id;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];

  static const empty = User('-');
}
```

Reference to the code: https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=user-repository

Here is my state class code:

```
class JLPTVoiceRecorderState extends Equatable {


  final JLPTVoiceRecorderStatus status;
  final LearningQuestion question;
  final File? voiceFile;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status, question, voiceFile];

  const JLPTVoiceRecorderState({
    required this.status,
    required this.question,
    this.voiceFile,
  });

}
```

Comment: being word `empty` , it would be nice to us empty string. I wouldn't make nullable if it doesn't accept null.  also we've sealed/abstract class, that may help

Comment: null has many overloaded meanings, being an in-band sentinel as well as sometimes a valid value.  If you want a clearly distinct sentinel, use something like fpdart's Option, or a custom abstract class that has some kind of "empty" sentinel subclass.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh in which situation we should use nullable object in dart. Can you give me a small example by your use case

Comment: When domain/API returns null.